# Remove files that don't begin with 'Builder'

Tags: macos

I need to make an update of a project on my webserver. Unfortunately others have already changed some of the files on the server, which I don't want to overwrite. I can securely overwrite all files that begin with "Builder" (like "BuilderUser.php" or "BuilderTemplate.php").

My idea was to copy my local directory and remove all files that don't begin with "Builder" and then upload the resulting folder. And I'm using OS X. Is there any way to remove all files that do not prefixed with "Builder"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a terminal, navigate to the root of your project, and type

```
find . -type f | grep -v '/Builder[^/]*' | xargs rm
```

`find` will print anything in `.` or subdirectories, of `-type f` meaning regular files (as opposed to block devices, symlinks, directories, etc.).  `grep` will print any line that (because of `-v`) *doesn't* match the pattern.  For the pattern, `/` indicates a directory, 'Builder' must be the first thing that appears after the directory (so in the filename), `[^/]` means any character except a `/` (directory separator), and `*` means any number of the last item (non-slashes).  `xargs` then takes files from the pipe and passes them as arguments to `rm`.

Note that this will only work on files without spaces in the name.  If you need one that handles spaces, post or look up zero-delimiting options in the man pages.